# install jenkins into weblogic

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, weblogic

I'm trying to install jenkins into weblogic server

If I deploy normally to weblogic, this error evoke.

> Error 500--Internal Server Error
>
> From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
>
> 10.5.1 500 Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from
>   fulfilling the request.

[image]

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Weblogic

in this article, It says make some code and drop to WEB-INF of war directory.

But I can not find WEB-INF of jenkins,and If I make WEB-INF, this error still evoke.

How Can I install jenkins into weblogic?

Comment: You should try another Stack Exchange site. Maybe http://superuser.com/ is the right place for this. Stack Overflow is the wrong place for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.
I was use jenkins 2.X version and this error evoke.
When I downgrade to 1.615.3 version, this error erased.
So you must use this version.